# strange stack trace with address sanitizer

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

Trying to debug a memory corruption with address sanitizer.  It detects error, read after free.  Read gives me a meaningful stack trace which makes sense, but then for the place were memory was allegedly freed i get weird one:

```
    #0 0xf793ba08 in operator delete(void*) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:165
ing<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >*, unsigned int) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:128
    #2 0xa0217ef in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > >&, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >*, unsigned int) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:469
    #3 0xa0217ef in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >*) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:584
    #4 0xa0217ef in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > >::_M_drop_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >*) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:651
    #5 0xa0217ef in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >*) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1920
    #6 0xa0217ef in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > >::~_Rb_tree() /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1000
    #7 0xa0217ef in std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, task::my_task_stats, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, task::my_task_stats> > >::~map() /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:300
    #8 0xf6e46f05  (/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x33f05)
```

What do I make of the destructor being called straight from libc? What makes it stranger is that this map that is being deleted is a static field in a class. Does this mean that the error happened when process was terminating?  How would i figure out why it is terminating?

Comment: Yes, looks like a global object destructor. *"figure out why it is terminating?"* Breakpoints on `exit()`, `abort()`, etc.

Comment: There is probably some handler (e.g. a registered exit handler registered with `std::atexit()`) being called from libc that does cleanup.  If your code hasn't set up that handler then, more than likely, the cause is some other part of your code (e.g.  some code molests a pointer so unintentionally overwrites some data used by library functions, poisons some data, and - possibly much later, in terms of program execution - triggers a problem that is detected by the address sanitizer).

Comment: hm so i guess a followup question -- how do I prevent multi-threaded programs from crashing like this on exit?

Comment: MK. It's usually simple (don't dereference iterators/references to items in your `std::map` after it's been destroyed) but if you want specific advice in your case, please show your code.

Comment: If there was a short/simple answer to that, nobody would ever have to debug software, since one could guarantee there are no bugs.   There aren't many options other than avoiding bugs in the first place (through program design, use of techniques that reduce the chances of mistakes, etc etc) or debugging (finding and stamping out bugs, and somehow ensuring - or praying - that new bugs aren't introduced).   With multi-threaded programs, design (e.g. to avoid race conditions, use of synchronisation, etc to avoid bugs) is even more important, because debugging becomes much harder.

Comment: By making sure everything you do is threadsafe?  Also this kind of crash can happen if you do string formatiing in an exception handler (and that itself throws an exception again)

Comment: I think the answer here is to not use static fields; ChatGPT advises me to use a snigleton pointer instead and initialize it using std::once_flag.  I think this is a valid advice.  Of course this will register as a leak on shutdown but i don't really care about that.

Comment: "singleton" + "sniglet" => "snigleton" pointer (*tee-hee*).  I've used "leaky singletons" before, which is okay if they don't really need to be destructed at exit.  The ones that don't need to be destructed are memory only resources (no files, no locks, no semaphores, no last gasp logging, or any other kind of "needs to be released" resources).  Exiting itself will reclaim the memory by the OS when the process terminates.

Comment: "how do I prevent multi-threaded programs from crashing like this on exit?". Just a thought, are you terminating all threads in an orderly fashion before the destructor is called. For example by ensuring threads a proceeding to termination and calling `join()` on the them to be certain they are terminated before starting to destroy potentially shared objects.

Answer (score 1):

> a followup question -- how do I prevent multi-threaded programs from crashing like this on exit?

By not making any global `C++` objects with non-trivial destructors.

> ChatGPT advises me to use a snigleton pointer instead and initialize it using std::once_flag.

That is one valid solution. Often you don't need the `std::once_flag` at all, e.g.

```
std::map<int, int>& GetGlobalMap()
{
  // new is guaranteed to execute only once.
  static auto *the_map = new std::map<int, int>();
  return *the_map;
}
```

> I think this is a valid advice. Of course this will register as a leak on shutdown

No, it will not. Any leak detector worth using makes a distinction between "leaked" (you've lost the pointer and couldn't `free` / `delete` even if you wanted to) and "still allocated at exit" (you could `free`, but haven't bothered to).

Comment: "Any leak detector worth using" - pretty sure valgrind reports this as a leak. Or is valgrind no longer considered worth using?

Comment: @MK. Valgrind does _not_ report this as a  leak. It reports it as "still reachable", which is different from leaks.